# django.contrib.comments.moderation.AlreadyModerated error in zinnia django

Tags: python, django, model, zinnia

I had a django app in which i am using `django-zinnia-blog` for my blog functionality.

**Issue One**

And now i updated `zinnia` with latest `github` version and i am getting the below wierd error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x941554c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/name/virtualenvironment/apps/proname/proname/apps/zinnia/models/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    moderator.register(Entry, EntryCommentModerator)
  File "/home/user/Envs/zinnia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/comments/moderation.py", line 305, in register
    raise AlreadyModerated("The model '%s' is already being moderated" % model._meta.module_name)
django.contrib.comments.moderation.AlreadyModerated: The model 'entry' is already being moderated
```

`django version -- 1.5.3`

So why it is displaying `AlreadyModerated` error when trying to update the `zinnia` witj latest version ?

**Issue Two**

Below are my `specs/setings`

**settings.py**

```
ZINNIA_ENTRY_BASE_MODEL = 'proname.apps.app_name.models.EntryBase'
ZINNIA_SAVE_PING_DIRECTORIES = False
ZINNIA_PING_EXTERNAL_URLS = False
```

Actually i am trying to extend the `Entry` model as below

```
from zinnia.models_bases.entry import AbstractEntry

class EntryBase(AbstractEntry):
    pass

    class Meta(AbstractEntry.Meta):
        abstract = True
        verbose_name_plural = _("Entry")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Entries")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Entry %s' % self.title
```

`django version -- 1.4.5`

When i used above django version i am getting an extra error along with above one

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured('%s cannot be imported' % model_path)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: zinnia.models_bases.entry.AbstractEntry cannot be imported
```

So can anyone please let me know to solve the above issues like

`AlreadyModerated` when updating to latest github zinnia code

Trying to extend the `Entry` model ?

and made the zinnia work correctly ?

Comment: I have same error ...did u find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I figure out the problem changing version of zinnia to 0.14.3

> Zinnia 0.15 only works with django 1.7
>
> Use v0.14.3 instead.
>
> (*https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues/388*)

Comment: To make this a useful answer it needs to contain enough detail to answer the question even if the link to an external website stops working. An answer consisting just of a link is not considered acceptable on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue too. The way I was able to fix it was to link back to the model_bases folder in the original zinnia package. In my site's 'zinnia' folder (where the updated South migrations are stored):

```
$ ln -sf <python-path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zinnia/models_bases .
```